# Changing variable of second order differential operator

Tags: calculus, change-of-variable

If I have the variable

$g= r_g \cos(\theta_g)$

And then need to convert the operator:

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial g^2}$

into terms of $r_g$ and $\theta_g$ only.

Is the following correct?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial g} = \frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_g} + \frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g} $

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial g^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial g} \frac{\partial}{\partial g} =\bigg(\frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_g} + \frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g} \bigg)^2 = \frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_g} \frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_g} + \frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g}\frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g} + 2\frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta_g} \frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} = \bigg(\frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \bigg)^2 \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial \theta_g^2} + \bigg(\frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g}\bigg)^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r_g^2} + 2 \frac{\partial r_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial \theta_g}{\partial g} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_g} \frac{\partial }{\partial r_g}$

I am quite sure that it is, but applying this to a known function yields answers that I know are incorrect.
I have checked >dozen times and obtain the same result each time, so I am full of doubt and have none to ask for this sanity check in person.....
Please help?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like this? Of course, I'm only differentiating once, not twice, but you can repeat. If $F=F(x,y)$, $x = x(r,\theta)$ and $y=y(r,t)$, then 
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial r}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial \theta}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\d}{\partial}
\newcommand{\t}{\theta}
\newcommand{\dg}{\partial_{g}}
\newcommand{\dr}{\partial_{r}}
\newcommand{\dt}{\partial_{\theta}}
\newcommand{\dgg}{\partial^2_{gg}}
\newcommand{\dg}{\partial_{g}}
$
You are correct about the first derivative, but for the second one you need to use chain rule:

\begin{align}
\partial_{g}\left(\partial_{g}\right) &= \partial_g \left(r_g\partial_{r_g} + \t_g\partial_{\theta_g} \right)
 = \partial_g \left(r_g\partial_{r_g} \right) + \partial_g \left(\t_g\partial_{\theta_g} \right)
\\ &= r_{gg}\partial_{g} + r_g\partial_{g}\left(\partial_{r_g}\right) + \t_{gg}\partial_{\theta_g} + \t_g \partial_{g}\left(\partial_{\theta_g}\right)
\\&= r_{gg}\partial_{g} + r_g\left(r_g\partial_{r_g} + \t_g\partial_{\theta_g}\right)\partial_{r_g} + \t_{gg}\partial_{\theta_g} + \t_g \left(r_g\partial_{r_g} + \t_g\partial_{\theta_g}\right)\partial_{\theta_g}
%\\ = r_{gg}\partial_{g} + r_g^2\partial_{r_g}^2 + 2 r_g\t_g\partial_{r_g}\partial_{\theta_g} + \t_{gg}\partial_{\theta_g} + \t_g^2\partial_{\theta_g}^2
\end{align}

Expanding parenthesis and collecting alike terms yeilds
$$
\partial_{g}\left(\partial_{g}\right) = r_g^2\partial_{r_g}^2 + 2 r_g\t_g\partial_{r_g}\partial_{\theta_g}  + \t_g^2\partial_{\theta_g}^2 + r_{gg}\partial_{g} + \t_{gg}\partial_{\theta_g}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this, I had applied the chain rule for the first term, and then just...not done that for the second.
Thus missing two important terms.
I lament my puny human brain and it's lack of focus. :)